# Delete a PageLayout programatically

Tags: publishing, page-layout

In a publishing site, I want to delete a specific page layout. This code snippet is within a `FeatureDeactivating` event. `layout.Folder` is returning null, but I need the folder to delete the PageLayout.

```
SPSite site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;
if (PublishingSite.IsPublishingSite(site))
{
   PublishingSite pubSite = new PublishingSite(site);

   SPContentType ct = site.RootWeb.ContentTypes["Custom Page"];

   string layoutURL = site.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/" + pageLayoutName;
   PageLayout layout = pubSite.PageLayouts[layoutURL];
   SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder("_catalogs/masterpage");
   pubSite.PageLayouts.Delete(pageLayoutName, folder);
   folder.Files[layoutURL].Delete();
}
```

When I try to run the code, I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:fileUrl

**Edit 1**

I missed 2 lines of code. I'm tried to pass in a folder object (because layout.Folder is null). The passed in folder object returns the ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

**Edit 2**

Following James' suggestion, I modified the code as the following:

```
string layoutURL = site.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/" + pageLayoutName;
PageLayout layout = pubSite.PageLayouts[layoutURL];
SPList masterpageGallery = site.GetCatalog(SPListTemplateType.MasterPageCatalog);
pubSite.PageLayouts.Delete(pageLayoutName, masterpageGallery.RootFolder);
```

But I'm still getting the same error

Comment: It appears to be a URL format problem. While debugging did you check format of folder.Files[0].Url and format of layoutURL? the Delete method expects a site-relative URL.

Comment: The Delete method is expecting an SPFolder object

Comment: I see your problem.. Make sure the Page Layout name is WITHOUT file name extension as documented in SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MasterPage Gallery is actually a document library, you want to remove the page layout from the RootFolder of that library (which you can get via List.RootFolder).

Use [GetCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.getcatalog.aspx) to get the List, then get the folder via RootFolder.

Comment: This didn't work. See my Edit 2

Comment: When you use my suggestion, where is the error thrown? Looking more closely, I'm wondering how you get the pageLayoutName variable, too. Make sure it ends in aspx.

Comment: The error is thrown when trying to run the Delete method. pageLayoutName is a string defined in the EventReceiver. It DOES end in aspx. I'm able to get my PageLayout object using that url I create. When I hover over "RootFolder" of masterpageGallery.RootFolder in the Delete method, it shows me "_catalogs/masterpage"

Comment: Is there any implication of getting the SPListItem directly (since I have the URL) and deleting it that way? I'm unsure because it is a page layout

Comment: You can try, but I have a feeling you'll need to delete it from the PageLayouts collection, otherwise when you go to "Create a new Publishing Page", you'll get an ASP.NET error saying sharepoint can't find the list item associated with a page layout.

Comment: The RootFolder name you're getting does seem to be correct though... is it still the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` you're getting?

Comment: That's why I'm hesitant to just manually delete the list item. Also, what about deleting a page layout that has pages that are based off of it? Are you required to delete them too? That's why I thought the PageLayouts.Delete method would be the best route.

Comment: I just had a look in Reflector - seem the PageLayoutCollection.Delete method just deletes the SPFile anyway! Doesn't do any checking on usage of the page layout at all! I'm not sure if a Page whose layout is missing is automatically detatched if you try to open it, or throws an error. The Publishing Infrastructure is so flimsy imo.

Comment: I just found that if you try to view a page with a layout that no longer exists (at least the ASPX page no longer exists), you'll get an error page. Perhaps the best solution is to delete the list item, then remove it from the collection.

Now the tricky part is to efficiently find all pages of that layout.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, you just need to a SiteDataQuery where the content type starts with the associated content type of the page layout. I just got that same error you got when trying to delete the page layout, looks like it might be below the Managed API where it checks its usage (which, to be fair, would be a 2-line SQL query compared to the SPSiteDataQuery stuff you're gonna have to do to get the same results).

Comment: Or maybe removing it from the collection is just repeating what I just did. You're right. This is flimsy as hell.

Comment: This is one of the areas where the implementation has been vastly different to the rest of SharePoint. We'd expect a PublishingWeb.Layouts property, which returns a LayoutCollection object, which inherits from IEnumerable. We'd expect an indexer Item property, so doing PublishingWeb.Layouts["MyLayout"] would return a layout. But, alas, it wasn't us that wrote it :)

Comment: I sense another blog post coming once I figure this garbage out :)
Accepting as answer as I upvoted the comments that will lead to a solution

Comment: Cool. Yeah, I think you might be able to move the layout into a new folder, then delete that folder (I think I have used this in the past).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you have but I got the solution by below code.

```
            SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
            SPList list = web.GetCatalog(SPListTemplateType.MasterPageCatalog);
            PublishingSite pubSite = new PublishingSite(web.Site);
            pubSite.PageLayouts.Delete("ArchivePagePL", list.RootFolder);
```

This worked for me.